# Vaadin TextChangeListener, Table and loss of focus

Tags: vaadin

I need some help to solve a problem with a calculation updated by a TextChangeListener.

So I have a DTO who contains a quantity and a unit price.
In my table, I add an extra column with the value of quantity * unit price.

[image: screenshot]

With a TextChangeListener I would like to update the value of the column "Montant Total".
In the listener, I do that:

```
// I commit the change
myTable.commit();
// I need to refresh the row cache
myTable.refreshRowCache();
```

If I call "refreshRowCache()", the change will be done **BUT** I lose the focus in the field...
If I don't call the method, obviously the value of the column doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

In the vaadin forum [this](https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/250088) post explains what your need to do

Answer (score 0):

I use the myTextField.getCursorPosition() and myTextField.setCursorPosition to solve the problem.